# Image path save to the database

Tags: database, image, upload

I have an Image upload button. I want to save an image into a folder in my solution and save the path to the database. I used **FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(imgPath));**

But I got the error as

**Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\indian.......\ImageStorage\DSC01420.JPG'.**

How can I save the image to a folder and the path to the database and retrieve the same.

Comment: depends on the environment you're working with. one issue between browser is that some send the file name of the uploaded file and some the complete path information (now guess which one is offering the bullshit ? ;-)).

Answer (score 1):

```
       **LINK EACH PROGRAMS**
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
            <h3> Choose File to Upload in Server </h3>          
           <form action="Recent" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

            <input type="file" name="file" />
            <input type="submit" value="upload" />
            </form>          
        </div>


</body>
</html>
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    
    import java.sql.*;
    import java.io.*;

    import javax.servlet.ServletException;
    import javax.servlet.annotation.MultipartConfig;
    import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
    import javax.servlet.http.Part;
    import javax.servlet.annotation.MultipartConfig;
    import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
    import java.util.Hashtable;
    import java.util.List;

    import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem;
    import org.apache.commons.fileupload.ParameterParser;
    import org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory;
    import org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload;


    /**
     * Servlet implementation class Recent
     */
    @WebServlet("/Recent")
    @MultipartConfig
    public class Recent extends HttpServlet {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        /**
         * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
         */
        public Recent() {
            super();
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        /**
         * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
         */
        protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             Sample  s1=new Sample();
             final String UPLOAD_DIRECTORY = "/home/pradeep/Documents/pradeep/WebContent/Images";
             if(ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request)){
                    try {
             List<FileItem> multiparts = new 
                                ServletFileUpload(new DiskFileItemFactory()).parseRequest(request);

                        for(FileItem item : multiparts){
                            if(!item.isFormField())
                            {
                                String name = new File(item.getName()).getName();
                                item.write( new File(UPLOAD_DIRECTORY + File.separator + name));
                                String Path= "/home/pradeep/Documents/pradeep/WebContent/Images/" +name;


                              s1.connecting(Path);


                            }
                        }

                            request.setAttribute("message", "File Uploaded Successfully");
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                       request.setAttribute("message", "File Upload Failed due to " + ex);
                    }          

                }else{
                    request.setAttribute("message",
                                         "Sorry this Servlet only handles file upload request");
                }



                    request.getRequestDispatcher("/Result.jsp").forward(request, response);




        }

    }


    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     import java.sql.Connection;
        import java.sql.DriverManager;
        import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
        import java.sql.ResultSet;
        import java.sql.SQLException;

        import dbconnections.Connections;



        public class Sample {
            Connections con=new Connections();

            public void connecting(String Path)
            {
                Connection conn=con.Connect();

                PreparedStatement pst;
                String query="INSERT INTO Student1 (Path) values (?)";
               try {

                    pst=conn.prepareStatement(query);
                    pst.setString(1,Path);
                    pst.executeUpdate();

                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }


        }
```